# UrlRewriting rule does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following PHP code:

```
   <?php  
    if(isset($_GET['article']))
    {
        echo "<b>success</b>";
    }
 ?>
```

And this html:

```
<a href="http://localhost/PHPTest/index.php?article_27" >Click me</a>
```

I am trying to come up with my own url.

By doing so, I try to use mod_rewrite(). This is what is in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /PHPTest/

RewriteRule ^article_([0-9]+)$ index.php?article=$1
```

As you can see, I try to get the article get variable..

This however doesnt work.. The htaccess does not comprehend artcile_27, for example, as article=27..

Why is that?

What should happen is that the success word should be printed whenever I press the link. The problem is that it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?article_([0-9]+)$ index.php?article=$1
```

However, I'd question the use of mod_rewrite in this way.

First of all, if your url is always just `index.php?article_27` then you can get directly at "article_27" using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, without mod_rewrite at all.

If you're going to use mod_rewrite, why not have your URL be `/PHPTest/article/27`?

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+) index.php?article=$1
```

The above will also allow `/PHPTest/article/27/title_of_article_here`, which gives you two nice things: the ID is still there so it's easy to retrieve server-side, and the name is in the URL so it's nice to read as a human and helps search engines. If you look in your URL bar now, you'll notice stackoverflow itself uses this method.

Answer (score 2):

The rule you have written would match the link http://localhost/PHPTest/article_27, if you really want to have the URL http://localhost/PHPTest/index.php?article_27 matched (which is an, at least in my oppionion, unusual URL), the correct Rewrite Rule would be the following:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php\?article_([0-9]+)$ index.php?article=$1
```

You have to look at the whole part after the last slash.

Answer (score 1):

Open this: http://localhost/PHPTest/article_27

If it works, it means that your rewriting works. In that case, all you have to do is change the HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/PHPTest/index.php?article_27" >Click me</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="http://localhost/PHPTest/article_27" >Click me</a>
```

Or rather, just:

```
<a href="/PHPTest/article_27" >Click me</a>
```

Which makes your code more portable to another hostname, port, protocol ...